# CameraX bindToLifecycle crashes when extension mode is ExtensionMode.BOKEH and ExtensionMode.FACE_RETOUCH

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

When bindToLifecycle is called quickly after eachother with ExtensionMode.BOKEH or ExtensionMode.FACE_RETOUCH enabled camera the app crashes.

Other extensions such as ExtensionMode.HDR, ExtensionMode.NIGHT & ExtensionMode.AUTO work fine.

```
unbindAll() 
bindToLifecycle( lifecycleOwner, CameraSelectorWithExt, previewUseCase, imageUseCase )
```

the exception i get is:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {3edac13} is shutting down
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.HandlerScheduledExecutorService.createPostFailedException(HandlerScheduledExecutorService.java:184)
    at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.HandlerScheduledExecutorService.execute(HandlerScheduledExecutorService.java:179)
    at androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy.lambda$setOnImageAvailableListener$1$androidx-camera-core-AndroidImageReaderProxy(AndroidImageReaderProxy.java:141)
    at androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onImageAvailable(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.media.ImageReader$1.run(ImageReader.java:837)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: Which device you are testing?

Comment: @WasimAnsari Samsung Galaxy S20 SM-G980F/DS running Android 12.